# embedding multiple RunKit REPL instances on a single web page

Tags: runkit, remarkjs

I am creating a web-based presentation using [RemarkJS](https://remarkjs.com/#1), my preferred tool for presentations. Since I want to demo small bits of `nodejs` code, I want to use [RunKit](https://runkit.com/punkish/593f0350407b44001216f789)'s [REPL embedding capability](https://runkit.com/docs/embed). I couldn't quite figure out how to embed multiple instances on a single web page, but I managed to kludge something up by running the following code multiple times

```
var nb1 = RunKit.createNotebook({
    // the parent element for the new notebook
    element: document.getElementById("div1"),

    // specify the source of the notebook
    source: source1
})

var nb2 = RunKit.createNotebook({
    // the parent element for the new notebook
    element: document.getElementById("div2"),

    // specify the source of the notebook
    source: source2
})
```

and so on. This actually works, but is super-inefficient. When I launch my presentation, multiple calls to RunKit are made even though the entire page is loaded only once. Not only that, multiple calls to RunKit are made every time I change the slides, which, in RemarkJS, simple hides and displays different parts of the same, single web page. Since the web page itself is being loaded only once, RunKit should be called only once. At least, that is what I think (obviously, it seems I am wrong).

Finally, the actual RunKit REPL frame takes a while before it is rendered. In the beginning, only a few lines of truncated code shows up, but after a while of waiting, the entire frame gets rendered.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and figured it out. So for future users here is how you do it.

```
<script src="https://embed.runkit.com"></script>
<style>.embed { overflow: visible; }</style>
<pre class="embed" data-gutter="inside">console.log("hello inside");
1 + 1</pre>
<pre class="embed" data-gutter="outside">console.log("hello outside");
1 + 1</pre>
<pre class="embed" data-gutter="none">console.log("hello none");
1 + 1</pre>
<script>
const elements = [...document.getElementsByClassName('embed')]
const notebooks = elements.reduce((notebooks, element) => {
    const innerText = element.firstChild
    const currentCell = window.RunKit.createNotebook({
        element,
        gutterStyle: element.getAttribute("data-gutter"),
        source: innerText.textContent,
        // Remove the text content of the pre tag after the embed has loaded
        onLoad: () => innerText.remove()
    })
  return notebooks
}, [])
</script>
```

The sample is taken from here: https://runkit.com/docs/embed
Scroll down and you will find it.